# Where to put all the logic for a full ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, bootstrap-modal

I am really new to all the AJAX stuff and now I wanted to convert a small homepage I created with CakePHP to an full AJAX page.

The functions I use are mainly:

- View Dashboard with a List of "Book"s
- View a "Book"
- Create a "Book"
- Edit a "Book"
- Delete a "Book"

Each function uses its own view and should be shown in a modal. It is important that modals can overlap. In the beginning I added the JavaScript I needed to each view. So AJAX was loading the HTML view (+new AJAX) and displayed it in an modal. I was able to click on "View Book" and then "Edit Book", so two modals would overlap.

This was working fine, but Chrome threw a few warnings because it didn't like reloading AJAX.

So I decided to put all the AJAX logic into the Dashboard View and created an event handler for every possible button that could be clicked. Because my modals might overlap (and I don't know which ones would overlap) I created an empty div for every modal that could occur.

Currently it is working fine, but what if I add way more functionality? 
Would I need in my Dashboard View an empty div for every modal that could show up and do I have to load ALL the AJAX functionality when the page is loaded?

Where should I put all the logic? Do I load all at once, even though I might just use a tiny part of the logic? How would I handle many overlapping modals with different content?

I hope you got some advice for me, because I think my solution will make it a big mess as soon as the project grows.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

Comment: This is far to broad for a proper answer. There are several frameworks like AngularJS that come with exhaustive tutorials and documentation that explain how to build SPA (single page apps) with them. I recommend you to google for that term or go straight for Angular or any other framework that suits for SPA.

Comment: Too broad but in brief: you make your app have a (json) api and then you use it (however you want). Building an api is [pretty trivial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) or even [extremely trivial](https://github.com/friendsofcake/crud) - then you only need to read a tutorial for whichever js framework you want to use.

Comment: Okay, so you would suggest to use an JS framework. I was just wondering if there was a good way to create an SPA without switching to an JS framework. But I guess I will have a look at Angular then

Comment: If you don't want to use one write one. :P If it's your private fun feel free to reinvent the wheel as much as you want. It's a huge amount of work if done right. If you have a client I guess he won't be pleased if you take 10x the amount of time to come up with a proper SPA solution that is probably more than 10x more bad than any existing lib. :) You need at least a RESTful client lib in JS and some kind of data binding to deal with the data and API and you don't sound like you're familiar with any of the underlying concepts. So go for Angular, React + Backbone or something else.